# GAS gives unconsistent script execution results, why?

Tags: google-apps-script

The same code, the same input, different output ? Literally running same script one time completes, and 30 sec later next time it fails. All the form inputs are same, all sheet data / named ranges are same and unchanged. Also, when it fails, it outputs my console logs. When it completes, no logs are present. Is GAS playing chess with me or what is going on here ? The project is form connected with spreadsheet. Inside spreadsheet there is a "onFormSubmit" trigger, which then delegates to a library script. Now submitting exactly same form answers say 2 times, one will pass, the other will not. Also when it pass, it outputs no console logs, but when it fails the logs are visible in Script Executions window, on script.google.com. Any ideas ?

**EDIT**
I think it is worth to mention, that I try to force an error in my app, and see whether it get handled properly. I force error, by making one of my named ranges to be "#REF".

**EDIT2**

So this is my "client" script, which is a script located inside my Google Spreadsheet. This Spreadsheet is connected to the Google Form, which I am submitting. Then in this script, there is a "onFormSubmit" trigger, which refers exactly to the below method:

```
// ON FORM SUBMIT
function collectFormData(e) {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const rangesMap = Api.loadNamedRanges(ss);
    Api.checkNamedRangesErrors();
}
```

This is the manifest for client script:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Warsaw",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Gmail",
        "serviceId": "gmail",
        "version": "v1"
      }
    ],
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "API",
        "version": "0",
        "libraryId": "id of api script here",
        "developmentMode": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my api project, which is library for client script above, referenced by "Api":

```
let _stackedErrors = [];

/**
 * Loads values for all named ranges in Spreadsheet and stores them in NamedRangeMap.
 * @param  {Spreadsheet}  ss  Active spreadsheet
 * @returns  {Map}  Map loaded with values of all named ranges
 */
function loadNamedRanges(ss) {
    const namedRangesMap = new Map();

    // helper variables start
    const namedRanges = ss.getNamedRanges();
    const namedRangesDict = {};
    // helper variables end

    // load named ranges dict start
    namedRanges.forEach((namedRange) => {
        const name = namedRange.getName();
        namedRangesDict[name] = namedRange.getRange();
    });
    // load named ranges dict end

    // see if map is available in script cache start
    const cacheKey = "ranges-map";
    var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
    var cached = cache.get(cacheKey);
    if (!!cached) {
        return JSON.parse(cached);
    }
    // see if map is available in script cache end

    // load all named ranges start
    // for simplicity we have 2 named ranges: EMAIL and NAME
    // EMAIL is "#REF", NAME is valid named range with single cell
    let emailColumn = 0;
    const emailRange = namedRangesDict["EMAIL"];
    if ("EMAIL" in namedRangesDict) {
        emailColumn = emailRange.getColumn();
    } else {
        const error = new Error("Range with name EMAIL does not exist or refers to wrong cell !!!");
        _stackedErrors.push(error);
    }

    const nameRange = namedRangesDict["NAME"];
    let nameColumn = 0;
    if ("NAME" in namedRangesDict) {
        nameColumn = nameRange.getColumn();
    } else {
        const error = new Error("Range with name NAME does not exist or refers to wrong cell !!!");
        _stackedErrors.push(error);
    }

    namedRangesMap["emailCol"] = emailColumn;
    namedRangesMap["nameCol"] = nameColumn;
    // load all named ranges end

    // update cache start
    cache.put(cacheKey, JSON.stringify(rangesMap));
    // update cache end

    return namedRangesMap;
}
```

This method creates a Map object, where keys are names of all named ranges in Spreadsheet, and values are either their respective cell values / rows / columns.

Now here comes the second api method. This method checks if any errors happened during named ranges loading, and if yes, throws an error.

```
/**
 * Checks whether any errors happened during loading of named ranges.
 * If there were some, then they were saved in stackedErrors array.
 * Then they are checked here and if there were any, main error is thrown here.
 *
 * @trows  {Error}  Throws error only, when any errors happened during loading named ranges
 */
function checkNamedRangesErrors() {
    if (_stackedErrors.length > 0) {
        throw new Error("Some named ranges are missing or refer to wrong cells !!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: I am your fan man, respect for you bro, just got back home, pls give me a bit, will try to do my best

Comment: Api is undefined

Comment: Api is another project, which is connected into client script in manifest

Comment: im almost there,

Comment: I'm not interested in expending that much effort.  I'll let someone else help you.

Comment: But its finished now, dont You wanna look again now ?

Comment: @Cooper The problem why one time script succedes, and next time fails, is because of not caching stackedErrors array.

Comment: If you had added a [mcve] in the beginning I probably would not have gotten involved at all because I hardly ever use cache service.

Comment: Pls update your answer, it will be a pleasure to me bro

Comment: I was learning GAS from your stack overflow answers literally over last year, thank You for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get named ranges names:

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const nr = [];
  ss.getNamedRanges().forEach(r => nr.push(r.getName()));
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(nr))
}

Execution log
2:03:54 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:03:46 PM  Info    ["Range4","Range1","stopRow","Range2","Range3"]
2:03:56 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Could you please look at it now

Comment: The problem was with not caching stackedErrors array

Comment: Please feel free to update your question, I will accept, just read stacked errors from cache in top, and write them at the bottom

Comment: And could You also pls upvote back my post pls